# Porting to Solaris SPARC using Sun Studio 12

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile an object file using the code below.

```
//--Begin test.cpp
class A;

void (A::* f_ptr) ();

void test() {
    A *a;
    (a->*f_ptr)();
}
//-- End test.cpp
```

For GNU g++ compiler, it is able to compile the object file.

`$ g++ -c test.cpp`

But for Sun Studio 12 on a Solaris 10 (SPARC), it outputs an error.

`$ CC -c test.cpp`

> "test.cpp", line 7: Error: Cannot call through pointer to member function before defining class A.
>
> 1 Error(s) detected.

Is there a compiler flags to get the Sun Studio C++ compiler to build
the object file?  Is there another workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `#include <A.h>` in that file. The compiler needs to know what `class A` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that there are a lot of things that g++ lets you get away with that sunpro will complain about, and vice-versa.

Be prepared for a lot of this sort of thing.

GMan's answer looks right to me.